# POST Request not working - MongDB and Express JS using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I started working on a MERN App and am trying to write a restful api. Code is working fine. But POST Requests are not working.

moviemodel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const Movie = new Schema(
{
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    time: { type: [String], required: true },
    rating: { type: Number, required: true },
},
    { timestamps: true },
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', Movie)
```

moviectrl.js

```
const Movie = require('../models/moviemodel')

createMovie = (req, res) => {
const body = req.body

if (!body) {
    return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        error: 'You must provide a movie',
    })
}

const movie = new Movie(body)

if (!movie) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
}

movie
    .save()
    .then(() => {
        return res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            id: movie._id,
            message: 'Movie created!',
        })
    })
    .catch(error => {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error,
            message: 'Movie not created!',
        })
    })
}
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const movieRouter = require('./routes/movierouter')


const app = express()
const apiPort = 3000

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/cinema', { useNewUrlParser: 
true }, function(err, client) {
const db = client.db('cinema')
if(err) throw err;
console.log('Successfully connected')
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.use('/api', movieRouter)

app.listen(apiPort, () => console.log(`Server running on port 
${apiPort}`))
```

movierouter.js

```
const express = require('express')

const MovieCtrl = require('../controllers/moviectrl')

const router = express.Router()

router.post('/movie', MovieCtrl.createMovie)
router.put('/movie/:id', MovieCtrl.updateMovie)
router.delete('/movie/:id', MovieCtrl.deleteMovie)
router.get('/movie/:id', MovieCtrl.getMovieById)
router.get('/movies', MovieCtrl.getMovies)

module.exports = router
```

When I send a POST Request using the link localhost:3000/api/movie and send a JSON Data through Postman. There is no response.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFeMo.jpg

Comment: `MongoClient.connect()` is not the `mongoose` connection. You need `mongoose.connect()`. Basically your mongoose method on the model is just "hanging" waiting for a connection. Which has not been made. You might try [reading the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) instead of trying to piece together what to do based on reading parts of various tutorials, since you have confused the `MongoClient` ( which is the raw driver ) examples with `mongoose`.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.createMovie = async(req,res){
    try{
        const create = await ModelName.create(req.body)
        if(ceate){
            res.send("created")
        }else{
            res.send("error")
        }
    }catch(err){
        res.send(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your app and found that your database is hanging ...

Replace your database connection with this :

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/cinema';

mongoose.connect(url, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
}, console.log(`DB running on ${url}`));
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiHca.jpg